# SQL max value Y for each distinct X

Tags: sql, max

Is there a way to query a table in such a way as to get the max values for EACH x value? As in... say there are two columns in a table. Call it x and y. Is there a way to get the MAX(Y) for EACH X? So if x repeats

```
    X               Y 
    1               6
    1               7
    1               8
    1               8
    1               8
    1               9
    2               5
    2               5
    2               5
    2               4
    2               5
    3               3
    3               4
    3               6
    4               2
    4               4
    4               5
    5               2
    5               1
    5               5
```

the query would get the highest y value for x=1, the highest y value for x=2, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group by the column that should be distinct. Then all aggregate functions like `max()` are applied to each group

```
select x, max(y) as max_y
from your_table
group by x
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select X, MAX(Y)
from my_table
group by X
order by X;
```

This gets the MAX Y for each X value.